# PDO php pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination

I have been trying to add a secure pagination page (from MySQL database). After looking online for one that I think is SQJ-injection etc free I found:
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Pagination-with-PHP-and-PDO.html

However when I use this script I get the error:
AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method pager::getPagerData() in /path....to..etc/index.php on line 62

Line 62 is:

```
$pager = Pager::getPagerData($_SESSION['total_records'], $limit, $page);
```

Full code:

```
<?php

 /*** make it or break it ***/
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 /*** begin the session ***/
 session_start();

 /*** include the database connection class ***/
 include 'db.php';

 /*** include the pager class ***/
 include 'pager.php';

 /*** set the page name ***/
 $page_name = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

 /*** set the number of results per page ***/
 $limit = 20;

 /*** check the SESSION array for the total_records ***/
 if(!isset($_SESSION['total_records']))
 {
    try
    {
        /*** first get the count of records ***/
        $sql = "SELECT count(id) AS total FROM tablename";
        $stmt = db::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $_SESSION['total_records'] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $_SESSION['total_records'] = 0;
    }
 }
    /*** check for a page number in GET ***/
    if( filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, "page") == false)
    {
        /*** no page in GET ***/
        $page = 1;
    }
    /*** if the page number is not an int or not within range, assign it to page 1 ***/
     elseif(filter_var($_GET['page'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("min_range"=>1, "max_range"=>$_SESSION['total_records'])) == false)
     {
        $page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        /*** if all is well, assign it ***/
        $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
    }

 /*** if we have no results then there is no point in going on ***/
 if($_SESSION['total_records'] == 0)
 {
    $content = 'No Records Available';
 }
 else
 {
    /*** feed the variables to the pager class ***/
    $pager = Pager::getPagerData($_SESSION['total_records'], $limit, $page);

    /*** retrieve the variables from the pager class ***/
    $offset = $pager->offset;
    $limit  = $pager->limit;
    $page   = $pager->page;

    /*** begin the menu ***/
    $menu = '';

    /*** if this is page 1 there is no previous link ***/
    if($page != 1)
    {
        $menu .= '<li><a href="'.$page_name.'?page='.($page - 1).'">&lt;&lt; PREV </a></li>';
    }

    /*** loop over the pages ***/
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pager->num_pages; $i++)
    {
        if ($i == $pager->page)
        {
            $menu .= '<li class="selected">'.$i.'</li>';
        }
        else
        {
            $menu .= '<li><a href="'.$page_name.'?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>'."\n";
        }
    }

    /*** if we are on the last page, we do not need the NEXT link ***/
    if ($page < $pager->num_pages)  
    {
        $menu .= '<li><a href="'.$page_name.'?page='.($page + 1).'"> NEXT &gt;&gt;</a></li>';
    }

    /*** our sql statement ***/
    $sql ='SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset';

    /*** run the query ***/
    $db = db::getInstance();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    /*** the elements table content ***/
    $content = '';
    foreach ($res as $el)
    {
        $content .= '
        <tr><td>'.$el['id'].'</td>
        <td>'.$el['metatitle'].'</td>
        <td>'.$el['date'].'</td></tr>';
    }
 }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>PHP Pagination</title>
<style type="text/css">

ul{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 395px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

li{
    display:inline;
}

li.selected{
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom: solid 1px red;
}

a{ 
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:green;
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

a:hover{
    border-bottom: solid 1px red;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

table {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

</style>
</head>

</body>

<ul>
    <?php echo $menu; ?>
</ul>

<table class="elements">
<thead>
<tr> <th>Atomic Number</th> <th>Latin</th> <th>English</th> </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <?php echo $content; ?>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr><th colspan="3">Table of elements</th> </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

pager.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Example usage
 * $pager = new pager();
 * $pager->num_results = $product_count;
 * $pager->limit = $config->config_values['product']['display_num'];
 * $pager->page = $page_num;
 * $pager->menu_link = '/category/electrical';
 * $pager->menu_link_suffix = '/foo/bar'; ( optional )
 * $pager->css_class = 'fubar'; ( optional )
 * $pager->run();
 * echo $pager;
 *
*/

    class pager{

            /**
            *
            * Constructor, duh!
            *
            * @access       public
            * @param        $num_pages
            * @param        $limit
            * @param        $page
            *
            */
            public function __construct( $num_results=null, $limit=null, $page=null )
            {
                    if( !is_null( $num_results ) && !is_null( $limit ) && !is_null( $page ) )
                    {
                            $this->num_results = $num_results;
                            $this->limit = $limit;
                            $this->page = $page;
                            $this->run();
                    }
            }

            /**
            *
            * Settor
            *
            * @param        string  $name
            * @param        mixed   $value
            *
            */
            public function __set( $name, $value )
            {
                    switch( $name )
                    {
                            case 'menu_link_suffix':
                            case 'num_results':
                            case 'menu_link':
                            case 'css_class':
                            case 'num_pages':
                            case 'offset':
                            case 'limit':
                            case 'page':
                            $this->$name = $value;
                            break;

                            default: throw new \Exception( "Unable to set $name" );
                    }
            }

            /**
            *
            * Gettor
            *
            * @param        string  $name
            *
            */
            public function __get( $name )
            {
                    switch( $name )
                    {
                            case 'menu_link_suffix':
                            case 'num_results':
                            case 'menu_link':
                            case 'css_class':
                            case 'num_pages':
                            case 'offset':
                            case 'limit':
                            case 'page':
                            return $this->$name;
                            break;

                            default: throw new \Exception( "Unable to get $name" );
                    }
            }

            /**
             * @calculate paging inforomation
             *
             * @access public
             * @param int $num_pages
             * @param int $limit
             * @param $page
             * @return object
             *
             **/
            public function run()
            {
                    /*** the number of pages ***/
                    $this->num_pages = ceil( $this->num_results / $this->limit );
                    $this->page = max( $this->page, 1 );
                    $this->page = min( $this->page, $this->num_pages );
                    /*** calculate the offset ***/
                    $this->offset = ( $this->page - 1 ) * $this->limit;
            }

            /**
            *
            * return a HTML string representation of the pager links
            * The links are in an <ul> with a CSS class name
            *
            * @access       public
            * @retun        string
            *
            */
            public function __toString()
            {
                    $menu = '<ul';
                    $menu .= isset( $this->css_class ) ? ' class="'.$this->css_class.'"' : '';
                    $menu .= '>';

                    /*** if this is page 1 there is no previous link ***/
                    if($this->page != 1)
                    {
                            $menu .= '<li><a href="'.$this->menu_link.'/'.( $this->page - 1 );
                            $menu .= isset( $this->menu_link_suffix ) ? $this->menu_link_suffix : '';
                            $menu .= '">PREV</a></li>';
                    }

                    /*** loop over the pages ***/
                    for( $i = 1; $i <= $this->num_pages; $i++ )
                    {
                            if( $i == $this->page )
                            {
                                    $menu .= '<li class="active"><a href="'.$this->menu_link.'/'.$i;
                                    $menu .= isset( $this->menu_link_suffix ) ? $this->menu_link_suffix : '';
                                    $menu .= '">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    $menu .= '<li><a href="'.$this->menu_link.'/'.$i;
                                    $menu .= isset( $this->menu_link_suffix ) ? $this->menu_link_suffix : '';
                                    $menu .= '">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                            }
                    }

                    /*** if we are on the last page, we do not need the NEXT link ***/
                    if( $this->page < $this->num_pages )
                    {
                            $menu .= '<li><a href="'.$this->menu_link.'/'.( $this->page + 1 );
                            $menu .= isset( $this->menu_link_suffix ) ? $this->menu_link_suffix : '';
                            $menu .= '">Next</a></li>';
                    }
                    return $menu;
            }

    } /*** end of class ***/
    ?>
```

dp.php

```
<?php

class db{

/*** Declare instance ***/
private static $instance = NULL;

/**
*
* the constructor is set to private so
* so nobody can create a new instance using new
*
*/
private function __construct() {
  /*** maybe set the db name here later ***/
}

/**
*
* Return DB instance or create intitial connection
*
* @return object (PDO)
*
* @access public
*
*/
public static function getInstance() {

if (!self::$instance)
    {
    self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME", 'USER', 'PASS');;
    self::$instance-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
return self::$instance;
}

/**
*
* Like the constructor, we make __clone private
* so nobody can clone the instance
*
*/
private function __clone(){
}

} /*** end of class ***/

?>
```

Any ideas? Also if you see any code that you think is security weak, please feel free to point it out :)

Thanks in advance

p.s. removed the user/pass tablename etc for here

Comment: Your `pager` class starts with a lower case `p`, but you reference it with upper case. This might cause undesirable effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing line 62 to:

```
$pager = pager::getPagerData($_SESSION['total_records'], $limit, $page);
```

Your class was defined with a lower case 'p'.

However, unless there's some magic going on, that method still hasn't been defined anywhere, so I can't see how this will ever work. It might be best to get in touch with the author of the article and ask.

Note:

It is considered a best practice to start class names with upper case.

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

Comment: Hi, thanks. Sadly your are correct and it hasn't worked. Don't suppose you know of any secure pagination examples online? All the ones I look at seem to be either be incomplete (like this one) or not PDO (e.g mysqli or old mysql)

Comment: I think there's enough to go on in the example, as bad as it is. As a list of things to achieve: (1) get the total number of pages from PDO, (2) remember which page the user is on (can be stored is session as above), (3) make a widget to show the page information nicely, (4) add functionality to change page, (5) get that pages worth of data and display it. -- The example from the article is vastly over complicated, when you break it down like this hopefully it becomes reasonably easy.